# Elements limit for sorted hash of hashes

Tags: perl

I would like to sort the hash of hashes according to the value of one of the keys and print only the 5 best results. I tried to do it with while, but unfortunately it failed.

Example values

```
key1 = 1
key2 = 2
key3 = 3
key4 = 4
key5 = 5
key6 = 6
key7 = 7
```

My try:

```
my limit = 5;
while (my $keys (sort {$hoh{$b}{aaaa}<=>$hoh{$a}{aaaa}) && my $i <= $limit) {
  $i++;
  print "KEY: $keys VALUE1: $hoh{$keys}->{aaaa} VALUE2: $top_strategies{$keys}->{bbbb}   \n";
}
```

Expected result:

```
KEY: key1 VALUE1: 1 VALUE2: 3213
KEY: key2 VALUE1: 2 VALUE2: 312
KEY: key3 VALUE1: 3 VALUE2: 41
KEY: key4 VALUE1: 4 VALUE2: 414123
KEY: key5 VALUE1: 5 VALUE2: 532
```

My result:

```
syntax error at backtest.pl line 252, near "$keys ("
syntax error at backtest.pl line 252, near "}<=>"
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there any other solution to achieve this?

Comment: A little bit of context would have been nice. Like how do your hashes ('%hoh', '%top_strategies') actually look like (as an executable statement). A little complete script demonstrating the problem in its environment would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be using a `while` loop, as that'll repeatedly 'spin' your sort. `while` runs repeatedly when a condition is "true" and reshuffling your list multiple times is not what you want to be doing.

Also, when you're sorting something, you need to specify what to sort. You've told sort to use a subroutine (comparing `$hoh` elements) but without specifying *what* to sort based on that comparison. You *probably* want to sort `keys %hoh`.

First sort your list, then grab the first 5 elements.

You could do this with a 'for' loop:

```
my $count = 0;
my $limit = 5;
for my $key ( sort {$hoh{$b}{aaaa}<=>$hoh{$a}{aaaa}) keys %hoh ) { 
    print "$key $hoh{$key}{'aaaa'} $hoh{$key}{'bbbb'}\n";  
    last if $count++ > $limit;
}
```